# FAQ change - from phishing to social engineering

Tags: discussion

Clean and simple suggestion - could FAQ be change to list social engineering instead of only phishing (which is only one (tiny) part of social attacks)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Makes sense, so I've done that.